# Vert.x @ConsumeEvent for a List of events

Tags: vert.x, quarkus

Just a quick question related to a `@ConsumeEvent` method that has a list of objects. 
A full project example can be found [here](https://github.com/devisions/quarkus-land/tree/master/quarkus-vertx-events).

Long story short:

1. In the consumer side (see my [ConfigManager](https://github.com/devisions/quarkus-land/blob/master/quarkus-vertx-events/src/main/java/org/acme/config/ConfigManager.java) implementation), this method is accepted and it works just fine:

```
@ConsumeEvent(Config.EBA_CONFIG_RELOAD)
public String reload(ReloadConfigEvent event) { ... }
```

but a method like the one below makes the Quarkus startup to fail due to the error `ClassNotFoundException: java.util.List<org.acme.config.events.ReloadConfigEvent>`:

```
@ConsumeEvent(Config.EBA_CONFIG_RELOAD)
public String reload(List<ReloadConfigEvent> events) { ... }
```

2. Although a `MessageCodec` is being registered at startup (in another `@ApplicationScoped` class, see my [Config's onStart()](https://github.com/devisions/quarkus-land/blob/master/quarkus-vertx-events/src/main/java/org/acme/config/Config.java) method), it looks that this registration will happen so late in the process that the issue persists.

Any idea whether I could set an order of processing these two `@ApplicationScoped` beans, or if I could do the registration of the `MessageCodec` in another (more earlier considered) case?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections and arrays are not directly supported. What you already did is a good workaround, which is wrapping a collection into a class and use that class as an event.

One extra note is that you don't need to register codec because they are registered  automatically if they are used within `@ConsumeEvent`.

If you want to override an event codec, you can do as below

```
 @ConsumeEvent(value = Config.EBA_CONFIGS_RELOAD, codec = YourCodec.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So the takeaways are:

1. Collections and arrays are not (directly or indirectly) supported.

2. Registering a codec can indeed be contextual and handly provided within the `@ConsumeEvent`.

Can we get an official reference of this unsupported thingy?

Comment: Actually, I checked the source code. Maybe someone from Quarkus team will reply soon and confirm.